# combine two data frame with daily record and hourly record

Tags: r, time, dataframe

I have two data frames: A

```
     y_m_d SNOW
    1 2010-01-01  0.0
    2 2010-01-02  0.0
    3 2010-01-03  0.1
    4 2010-01-04  0.0
    5 2010-01-05  0.0
    6 2010-01-06  2.3
```

B:

```
            time     temp

   1 2010-01-01 00:00:00 20.00000
   2 2010-01-01 01:00:00 18.33333
   3 2010-01-01 02:00:00 17.00000
   4 2010-01-01 03:00:00 25.33333
   5 2010-01-01 04:00:00 23.33333
```

I want to combine two data frame based on time. A is a daily record and B is a hourly record. I want to fill the A record at the  beginning of each day at 00:00:00 and leave the rest of day blank.
The result should be look like this:

```
            time          temp     SNOW
   1 2010-01-01 00:00:00 20.00000   0.0
   2 2010-01-01 01:00:00 18.33333
   3 2010-01-01 02:00:00 17.00000
   4 2010-01-01 03:00:00 25.33333
   5 2010-01-01 04:00:00 23.33333
   6 2010-01-01 05:00:00 22.66667
```

Could you please give me some advice?
Thank you.

Comment: If your times are actually character data (i.e. not formatted dates/times), it's pretty simple: `A$time <- paste(A$y_m_d, '00:00:00'); merge(B, A[,-1], all.x = TRUE)`. If they _are_ formatted, it's oddly more work.

Comment: Should be merge(B, A[,-1], all = TRUE)?The result is not quite to my final results. It list temp and SNOW with NA on 2010-01-01 00:00:00 with two records

Comment: How should I fill SNOW at the last hour of the day? Like 23:00:00

Comment: Using `all = TRUE` will return the rows from both, which is not what you had above. If you want to fill with 23:00:00, just replace 00:00:00 in the `paste` above.

Comment: Thank you. This is most simple and elegant solution.

Comment: Because I have a very large data frame for B, contains 10 years hourly record and other features. If I merge A,B in such case, this is a memory consuming operation. It always remind me out of memory. Is that because while you are using merge, it works on generating three big data frames extensively?

Answer (score 0):

Here's a quick solution:

```
A$y_m_d <- as.Date(A$y_m_d)
B$SNOW <- sapply(as.Date(B$time), function(x) A[A$y_m_d==x, "SNOW"])
```

Comment: I need to fill SNOW  only for the beginning of each day  at "00:00:00" and leave all the other blank. Sorry I'm quite new to R and sometimes time handling is tricky.

Comment: If you change your A$y_m_d with `A$y_m_d <- paste(A$y_m_d, "00:00:00")` and run the sapply, you will get the desired output. Having said that, it's more preferable to repeat the day reading across the hours, to allow further calculation.

Answer (score 0):

This might not be the most efficient way in the world to do this, but it is a solution. I attempted to create data with the exact same variable types and structure as you.

```
# Create example data
y_m_d <- as.POSIXct(c("2010-01-01", "2010-01-02"), format="%Y-%m-%d")
SNOW <- c(0, 0.1)
time <- as.POSIXct(c("2010-01-01 00:00:00", "2010-01-01 01:00:00", "2010-01-01 02:00:00", "2010-01-02 00:00:00", "2010-01-02 01:00:00", "2010-01-02 02:00:00"), format="%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
temp <- rnorm(6, mean=20, sd=4)
A <- data.frame(y_m_d, SNOW)
B <- data.frame(time, temp)

# Check data
A
##        y_m_d SNOW
## 1 2010-01-01  0.0
## 2 2010-01-02  0.1
B
##                  time     temp
## 1 2010-01-01 00:00:00 17.52852
## 2 2010-01-01 01:00:00 12.42715
## 3 2010-01-01 02:00:00 21.79584
## 4 2010-01-02 00:00:00 19.90442
## 5 2010-01-02 01:00:00 16.40524
## 6 2010-01-02 02:00:00 16.86854

# Loop through days and construct new SNOW variable
days <- as.POSIXct(format(B$time, "%Y-%m-%d"), format="%Y-%m-%d")
SNOW_new <- c()
for (i in 1:nrow(A)) {
    SNOW_new <- c(A[i, "SNOW"], rep(NA, sum(days==A[i, "y_m_d"])-1), SNOW_new)
    }

# Create new data frame
C <- data.frame(B, SNOW_new)
##                  time     temp SNOW_new
## 1 2010-01-01 00:00:00 17.52852      0.1
## 2 2010-01-01 01:00:00 12.42715       NA
## 3 2010-01-01 02:00:00 21.79584       NA
## 4 2010-01-02 00:00:00 19.90442      0.0
## 5 2010-01-02 01:00:00 16.40524       NA
## 6 2010-01-02 02:00:00 16.86854       NA
```

I put `NA` rather than a blank space because I assume you want the `SNOW_new` variable to be numeric, not character. But if you do want a blank space, you can just replace the `NA` in the `rep` function with a `""`.

Answer (score 0):

Making sure time variables are in the right format.

```
A$y_m_d <- as.POSIXct(A$y_m_d, format="%Y-%m-%d")
B$time <- as.POSIXct(B$time, format="%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
```

The package lubridate is suited to merge time series data

```
#install.packages("lubridate")
library(lubridate)

A <- xts(A[,-1], order.by = A$y_m_d)
B <- xts(B[,-1], order.by = B$time)
merge.xts(A, B)
```